# How do I solve $\lvert \mathcal P(\{ 2,3,4 \}) \cap \{X : \lvert X\rvert = 2\} \rvert$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

How do I solve $\lvert \mathcal P(\{ 2,3,4 \}) \cap \{X : \lvert X\rvert = 2\} \rvert$

I fail to understand how to define $ X: |X| = 2$ , I know that it is all the x's that contain 2 elements. for e.g.$ \{\{2,3\},\{2,4\} ,\{3,4\}\}$ is one of them. but I fail to understand how to check the intersection between both of them. I'd love to get a hint or a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathcal{P}(\{2,3,4\})$ contains the eight subsets of $\{2,3,4\}$.  The second set is the "set" (really proper class) consisting of all sets that contain exactly two elements.  Hence their intersection is the set containing all the subsets of $\{2,3,4\}$ that contain exactly two elements.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the set of subsets of $\{2,3,4\}$ which contain two elements.

The intersection means that, of all possible size-2 sets in the universe, you are only looking for those that are also in the powerset.

$$\mathcal P\big(\{2,3,4\}\big)\cap\big\{X:\lvert X\rvert =2\big\} \;\equiv\; \Big\{X\in\mathcal P\big(\{2,3,4\}\big): \lvert X\rvert =2\Big\}$$